# How to set WinFormHost object dynamically?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I am wrapping Windows Form legacy control inside WPF control , I am doing this for a few Windows Form controls. ie:

```
 // WinFormHost control, only AWrapper is shown here, but there 
 //are BWrapper, CWrapper etc
 public class AWrapper : WindowsFormsHost 
 {
   Child=new ALegacyWinFormControl();
 }

//WPF control, similarly there are BControl, CControl etc
<UserControl x:Class="AControl">
    <local:AWrapper  />
</UserControl>
```

At my `ResourceDictionary` I am defining a key for each WPF controls

```
// each WPF control has a key
<ResourceDictionary>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AControlKey">
        <AControl />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BControlKey">
        <BControl />
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

There is one layer of duplication that I want to eliminate-- I will have to define each WPF control for each `WindowsFormsHost` wrapper, which is redundant. Is there anyway that I can do away with the `UserControl` object, and connect the `DataTemplate` straight with the `WindowsFormsHost` control? ie: I am looking at something like this:

```
// This wouldn't work
<ResourceDictionary>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AControlKey">
        <AWrapper/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BControlKey">
        <BWrapper/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

But the above doesn't seem to work. Anyway to make the above work? Is it possible at all?

Edit:

Comment: @dymanoid, oh yes. I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work provided that `AWrapper` is a `WindowsFormsHost`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AControlKey">
    <local:AWrapper/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Sample usage:

```
<ContentControl Content="." ContentTemplate="{StaticResource AControlKey}" />
```

No `UserControl` is involved.

`local` maps to the namespace in which the `AWrapper` class is defined:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
```